# Phone number to letter combination with recursive approach throwing a Null Pointer Exception

Tags: java

First of all, I'm trying build a program that print out all the possible letter combination based on the a phone number input.

My problem is that i cannot get my recursion function to work, I'm getting the follow error stack. The error is pointing to line 46 which is "`recursion("", line);` and line 65 which is `for (int i = 0; i < letters.length(); i++) {`

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at exercise.test.PhoneNumberCombo.recursion(PhoneNumberCombo.java:46)
    at exercise.test.PhoneNumberCombo.main(PhoneNumberCombo.java:65)
```

This is my code:

```
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;

public class PhoneNumberCombo {
    
          
          static void recursion(String combination, String next_digits) {
                
                List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
              
                Map<String, String> phone = new HashMap<String, String>() {{
                    put("2", "abc");
                    put("3", "def");
                    put("4", "ghi");
                    put("5", "jkl");
                    put("6", "mno");
                    put("7", "pqrs");
                    put("8", "tuv");
                    put("9", "wxyz");
                  }};
              
                // BASE CASE no more digits found
                if (next_digits.length() == 0) {
                    
                     // the combination is built
                    result.add(combination);
                    System.out.println(result);
                }
                
                else {
                  
                  String digit = next_digits.substring(0, 1);
                  String letters = phone.get(digit);
                  
                  for (int i = 0; i < letters.length(); i++) {
                    String letter = phone.get(digit).substring(i, i + 1);
                    
                  recursion(combination + letter, next_digits.substring(1));
                }
            }
             
      }
    
    
      public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
            
            InputStream phoneInputStream = IOUtils.toInputStream("123456", "UTF-8");
            
            InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(phoneInputStream);
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(reader);
            String line = in.readLine();
            
            if (line.length() != 0)
                recursion("", line);  
            
      }
}
```

Comment: What's the input from the file? It could be that `line` is `null`.

Comment: Have you debugged, on which `line` value does it fail? Isn't this `line == null`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously the failing line indicates that `letters` is `null`. For example, this will happen for `"0"` or `"1"`, which are not present in your `phone` map, or for any other `String`.

You have to handle case where `letters` is `null` right after `String letters = phone.get(digit)`. Whether to skip this `String` or throw an explicit exception about non-appropriate symbol.

Comment: It worked!!. Thanks a bunch, I've been scratching my head for quite some time. I actually added 1 and 0 key value pairs to the map and that did the trick, if it's not, too much to ask, can you  please show me an example how will it look like when handling the exception you mentioned?